# Comment on outdated question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

About 7 months ago I asked a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739606/embeddedid-with-foreign-keys-mapsid-only-works-with-joincolumn

This concerns Java and I am not working with Java for over half a year. Needless to say this question should have been deleted. Now out of the blue someone commented on my question.

What should I do with this question?

If I delete the question, the fellow who commented doesn't get a response and I think this is quite rude. If I comment to explain the story and the user doesn't responds on my comment I have to assume after a couple of days that he read it and then delete it.

I can also vote to close, but this seems weird to me, as it is my question.

Deleting the question seems like the better idea since the question had >300 views and no votes at all. Should I wait for it to be purged automatically?

Comment: If you don't want to be involved in the question just ignore it, one day someone may answer it and one day it may be useful to someone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not your Java guy, but question seems pretty OK. There is a code, it shows you have tried and so on. So deleting it would be a bit sad. On the other hand it probably would not push you into question ban. So there are 2 possibilities, really:

1. You have that program somewhere and can still test it. If so, try to put sane amount of time to get this answered for future, or for peers that took this from you. Or for the sake of the guy who came there wanting to help.
2. You can't do a thing about it, no access to software anymore and / or no time. In that case question would stay effectively unanswered forever no matter what, and that's pointless. You may delete it and if someone will encounter this again, he will be able to ask - and proceed to find an answer. Or just leave it with a comment saying you are unable to proceed with it anymore.

In both cases leaving a reply comment to the DuncanKinnear (commenter) with quick explanation or link to this meta question and waiting a day or six for his opinion would be polite.